# timer.setText("setTextHere") does not work inside the thread

Tags: android, multithreading, settext

`timer.setText("setTextHere")` does not work inside the thread.

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(){ 

            TextView timer;
            int t;
            public void run(){
                timer=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);      
                try{
                    timer.setText("setTextHere");
                    sleep(5000);


                }
                catch(Exception e){ 
                    e.printStackTrace();                        
                }
                finally{
                    Intent new1 = new Intent("com.example.app1.MENU");
                    startActivity(new1);                    
                }                   
            }               
        };
        thread1.start();
```

Comment: What it is showing???

Comment: use [Activity.runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) for accessing or Updating UI from Thread

Comment: timer=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);  this should be in the UI thread. and you can perform UI changes only on UI thread.

Comment: have a look at these topics http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+update+ui+from+separate+thread

Comment: u have to declare textview outside the thread!!!

Comment: Am a beginner. Thanks for suggestions. I wil try with those and get back here.

Comment: What is the difference in UI thread and ordinary thread. Can you suggest any pages where i can learn about that? Thanks alot for suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

```
_t = new Timer();
_t.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            _count++;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui thread
             {
              public void run() 
              {
                _tv.setText( "" + _count );
              }
             });
        }
    }, 1000, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot touch UI from background thread. Try to use AsyncTask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

On your onCreate() add:

```
h = new Handler();
```

add this somewhere:

```
class SetText implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
       // do UI task
       timer.setText("setTextHere");
    }
}
```

on someFunction() modify like this:

```
...
try 
{
    h.post( new SetText() );
    sleep(5000);
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final TextView timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            timer.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    timer.setText("setTextHere");
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Intent new1 = new Intent("com.example.app1.MENU");
            startActivity(new1);
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use this and initialize the setText before initializing the Thread

```
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(){ 


        int t;
        public void run(){    
            try{
                sleep(5000);


            }
            catch(Exception e){ 
                e.printStackTrace();                        
            }
            finally{
                Intent new1 = new Intent("com.example.app1.MENU");
                startActivity(new1);                    
            }                   
        }               
    };
    TextView timer;
    timer=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);  
    timer.setText("setTextHere");
    thread1.start();
```